# http inline box include some line

Tags: php, css, http

in the view part view.php

```
 <div class="data-img" style="float:right;width:220px;margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:20px;">
        <h3><? echo MyHtml::encode(implode(", ", $model->getDatasetTypes()));?></h3>
        <? if (isset($model->image)) {
            $url = $model->getImageUrl();
            /*
            if (substr($model->image->url, 0,6) != 'http://' && substr($model->image->url, 0,5) != 'ftp://') {
                $url = $model->image->url;
        }*/
            echo '<a href="'.$url.'">';
            echo MyHtml::image($url? $url : $model->image->image('image_upload'),
                            $model->image->image('image_upload'),
                            array('class'=>'image-hint','title'=>'<ul style="text-align:left;"><li>'.$model->image->tag.'</li><li>'.'License: '.$model->image->license.'</li><li>'.'Source: '.$model->image->source.'</li><li>'.'Photographer: '.$model->image->photographer.'</li></ul>'));
            echo '</a>';
        } else echo''; ?>
        <? echo 'Funding:'.'<br>'; 
           echo 'Funding body - NIH(National Institute of Health)'.'<br>';
           echo 'Location - USA'.'<br>';
        ?>
    </div>
```

I want to add a inline box(width is equal to data-img), put this part into inline box

```
 <? echo 'Funding:'.'<br>'; 
           echo 'Funding body - NIH(National Institute of Health)'.'<br>';
           echo 'Location - USA'.'<br>';
        ?>
```

how can i do it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I don't quite understand what you are asking. Do you mean adding inline styling to your echo'd text? If so you can just add your inline styling or a css class/id within the echo as you would write the html. The echo is within the data-img div so just style it to how you want with a 100% width.

eg:

```
  <? echo '<div class="my-inline-box"> Funding:'.'<br>'; 
       echo 'Funding body - NIH(National Institute of Health)'.'<br>';
       echo 'Location - USA'.'<br></div>';
    ?>
```

Then create the css for my-inline-box.
Sorry if I am misunderstanding hope it helped.

Comment: thanks, it's right. actually, i don't know how to write the css part.

Comment: You could use inline styling if you are unfamiliar with it (I wouldn't recommend it for common use) In that case where I declared the <div class="my-inline-box"> instead use <div style="color:red; border:2px solid;"> this would give you all red content with a 2px solid border. Start from there and find styles to make it your box :)